# Discord.js mongoose registering 2 warnings instead of one

Tags: discord.js

I am having issues across all the commands that share the same system as this one below.

All commands like ban, mute, kick are identical to this one and act the same in the mongoose part.

Take a look below, in the given code block.

```
                const warnDoc = new WarningModel({
                    guildID: message.guild.id,
                    memberID: member.id,
                    warnings: [reason],
                    moderator: [message.member.id],
                    date: [Date.now()],
                })

                warnDoc.warnings.push(reason)
                warnDoc.moderator.push(message.member.id)
                warnDoc.date.push(Date.now())

                await warnDoc.save().catch(err => console.log(err))

                message.delete(message.author);

                const logs = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "albot-mod-system");
                if (!logs)
                    return console.log(`No logs channel exists in ${message.guild.name}`)

                let warnembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle(`Moderation | Audit Log`)
                    .addField("**Member**", `${member}`)
                    .addField("**Action**", "Warn")
                    .addField("**Reason**", `${reason ? `${reason}` : ''}`)
                    .addField("**Warning Count**:", `${warnDoc.warnings.length}`)
                    .setTimestamp(message.createdAt)
                    .setFooter(message.member.displayName, message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
                    .setColor(`#000000`)
                logs.send(warnembed);
                member.send(`You were warned in **${message.guild.name}** for: **${reason}**.`);

        let warnEmbed2 = new MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor(`Moderation`)
            .setDescription(`${member} has been warned successfully with the reason: ${reason}`)
            .setTimestamp(message.createdAt)
            .setFooter(message.member.displayName, message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
            .setColor(`#000000`)
        message.channel.send(warnEmbed2);

    }
}
```

This is my warn command and when i run it, it normally gives 1 warning, but instead registers two. This issue came out of nowhere and it is confusing.

Anyone know the root issue of this?

Stuff ive tried:

Try a older mongoose version, no luck.
Play around with the mongoose parts in the code, no luck.
Revert to older versions of the command, no luck.

I honestly do not know what is causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're initializing `WarningModel` with a `warnings` array (`warnings: [reason]`) and pushing to it again with the same reason. Remove the push call.

Remove

```
warnDoc.warnings.push(reason)
```

You should also remove the following lines since `moderator` and `date` values are set while initializing the document.

```
warnDoc.moderator.push(message.member.id)
warnDoc.date.push(Date.now())
```

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow and respond to you as soon as possible as it's late for me.

Comment: Nope! doesnt work, it still thinks its doing 2 warnings and now its not even registering them on the database....

Comment: Actually, it worked, nevermind what i said. Thank you!

Comment: @nikoszz No worries!

Comment: 1 more issues popped up now, only one working shows up on it. So i guess the push calls were making the warnings pop up in one database entry and show them in a list like Warning ID: 2, 3 etc.

Comment: @nikoszz Can you clarify the issue?